# How can I make a dynamic download page PHP?

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm struggling to a problem. I've got a little upload script which is working fine! But I want to make anything similar like the modern download and upload websites. (FRee and Premium Downloads)

My situation right now is the following;

I can pass through a GET variable (file) which contains the filename.. Than the link which the user is getting to redirected to is; `localhost:8888/uploads/download.php?file=filename.zip`

But what I want to have, is that there is a link similar like; `localhost/uploads/file/2d618s` which does not contain the filename.

So what my question is; How can I make a link similar like; `localhost/uploads/file/dsa827 <- Unique name` per file instead of `localhost/uploads/download.php?file=filename.zip`

Below you can see the script which makes a link;

```
protected function get_download_url($file_name, $version = null, $direct = false) {
        if (!$direct && $this->options['download_via_php']) {
            $url = $this->options['script_url']
                .$this->get_query_separator($this->options['script_url'])
                .$this->get_singular_param_name()
                .'='.rawurlencode($file_name);
            if ($version) {
                $url .= '&version='.rawurlencode($version);
            }
            return $url.'&download=1';
        }
```

How my download template is looking like;

```
<p class="name">
            <form name='download' id='downloadForm' method='POST' action=''>
                {% if (file.url) { %}<p>{%=file.name%}</p>
                    <a href="download.php?file={%=file.name%}" title="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%} name="{%=file.name%}" onclick="document.forms['download'].submit();">Download</a>
                {% } else { %}
                    <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
                {% } %}
            </p>
            </form>
```

You can also point it out as a shortlink link which many modern upload websites does have... (uploaded.net/file/daj18si -> ul.to/daj18si)

similar like that :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: for each uploaded file you create a hash, and store the hash <-> filename relation in a database

Comment: Any explanation on that? Tried various methods, but didn't work very well for me..

Comment: `$hash = hash('sha256', $filename);` then put `$hash` and `$filename`  into a database table with 2 columns and everytime a user calls your link with a hash you look via `SELECT filename FROM hashtable WHERE hash='$hash'` for the corresponding filename

Comment: What is your database structure for the uploaded files? Also, are you storing the files above or below the public root?